# Is it possible to create and Auto Scaling Group Launch config with the CLI and define the instance tags in one command?

Tags: amazon-web-services, autoscaling

Is it possible to create and Auto Scaling Group Launch config with the CLI and define the instance tags in one command?

Maybe I am missing something but right now it looks like have to do it in two steps.

i.e.

```
aws autoscaling create-launch-configuration ...
```

and then

```
aws autoscaling create-or-update-tags --tags ...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you need to have asg LC created first to tag it, it is two step process as you mentioned. 
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/autoscaling/create-launch-configuration.html

This example creates a launch configuration based on an existing instance. In addition, it also specifies launch configuration attributes such as a security group, tenancy, Amazon EBS optimization, and a bootstrapping script:

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/autoscaling/ec2/userguide/autoscaling-tagging.html

`aws autoscaling create-launch-configuration --launch-configuration-name my-launch-config --key-name my-key-pair --instance-id i-7e13c876 --security-groups sg-eb2af88e --instance-type m1.small --user-data file://myuserdata.txt --instance-monitoring Enabled=true --no-ebs-optimized --no-associate-public-ip-address --placement-tenancy dedicated --iam-instance-profile my-autoscaling-role`

`aws autoscaling create-or-update-tags --tags "ResourceId=my-asg,ResourceType=auto-scaling-group,Key=environment,Value=test,PropagateAtLaunch=true"`